# PHP return 1 number after dot in float

Tags: php

I have got this php code

```
$Likes=1112;
$Likes=$Likes/1000;
echo $Likes."k";
```

This code returns me 1.112k,but my goal is to get 1.1k

Comment: Rounding will return 1 @FirstOne

Comment: No, I mean, if the value is eg `1.190`, should it be `1.1` or `1.2`?

Comment: @FirstOne it should return 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function:

```
echo number_format($Likes,1)."k";
```

---

And a coding style advice: don't start your variables with an upper case letter!

Comment: Thanks it worked and why?

Comment: The `why` is probably in the linked docs...